# How to debug App on local IIS instead of IIS Express with database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, deployment, iis-express

I created virtual directory and set droplist to *Local IIS*. App works but it cannot connect to database. My connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ICGuide-20180430032802.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ICGuide-20180430032802;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What did I wrong and how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Since you're using LocalDB, please make sure that there is `App_Data` folder in your website folder and that an AppPool user have rights to write into it.

You may need to check the created website folder and AppPool using IIS Management Console.

**Original Answer:**
Since application is started under IIS, it runs inside AppPool under its own user, not your local windows user. And that user may have no rights to connect to SQLEXPRESS server.
You may overcome that by two ways:

- Grant access to SQLEXPRESS for an AppPool windows user.
- Creata a non-windows user in your SQLEXPRESS and set that credentials in the connection string.